# Selenium webdriver : How to get embedded image data using JavaScripts?

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have to get the src from below mentioned html, please let me know how can I get the embedded image data? Is this possible using JS? If there is any way to show to the hide elements? I am using Selenium web driver with Java.

```
<div id="sc859" class="atv4 alc sc-view c-image sc-hidden" style="left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px">
    <img style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAJAAAP///wAAACH5BAUQAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICBAEAOw==" class="alc-img"/>
</div>
```

My code:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#sc859")); 
String imgeJs = (String) jse.executeScript("document.getElementsById('sc859')[0].getAttribute('src');", element);
System.out.println(imgeJs);
```

Comment: What do you mean by hidden attributes?

Comment: You can see the html? When I try to get the src it always  shows null? JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#sc859"));
  String imgeJs=(String) jse.executeScript("document.getElementsById('sc859')[0].getAttribute('src');", element);

Comment: That's called "embedded" image data,  not "hidden"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WebElement div = driver.findElement(By.id("sc859"));
String image =  div.findElement(By.className("alc-img")).getAttribute("src");

System.out.println(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

I never had luck using `document.getElementsById('sc859')[0].getAttribute('src');"` before. I always execute script directly like the following. Hope this is what you wanted. And, `src` does not exist on `div` rather on following `img` tag so your selector was wrong.

```
String src = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.querySelector(\"#sc859>img\").getAttribute(\"src\");");

System.out.println(src);
```

Print

```
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAJAAAP///wAAACH5BAUQAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICBAEAOw==
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use JavaScript, also, you can shorten Francesco's answer like this:

```
String src = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#sc859 > img.alc-img")).getAttribute("src");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 things u r doing wrong -

1 - **getElementsById** its `getElementById` which will return you only single element not a collection of it. There is no method getElementsById as far as i know.

2 - you are missing **return** in your executeScript method.

3 - There is no src attribute attached to div element whose id you have passed. src is attached to only img attribute.

So finally your code should be something like:

```
String imgeJs = jse.executeScript("return document.getElementById('sc859').childNodes[1].getAttribute('src')").toString();
```

or you can also achieve it by:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#sc859" > img.alc-img));
String imgeJs = jse.executeScript("return arguments[0].getAttribute('src')", element).toString();
```

Or else follow rest of the answers where you can simply get it done by `element.getAttribute("src")` method of WebElement interface.